# Match request data in Apache Httpd.conf

Tags: regex, apache

I want to match request parameters in httpd.conf if the request has malicious data i want to return 404 http status code to the client. Request data should have number , words and & = sign .If there is anything apart from this in request we don't have to process the request further

How we can do this Apache 2.2

Invalid URL :

```
http://ip/index.html?daa=1; rm /tmp/f;mkfifo /tmp/f;cat /tmp/f%7C/bin/sh -i %26
```

Valid URL

```
http://ip/index.html?daa=1&data=1
```

After adding :

```
<Directory "folder/scripts">
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} !^[a-zA-Z0-9&=?\-]*$
    RewriteRule . test.html [R=404,L]
</Directory>
```

It is not redirecting to my test.html page

Comment: Did you find any thing to achieve this?

Comment: I haven't found something , only this link http://www.ladadadada.net/articles/apache_regex_guide

Comment: http://ip/index.html?daa=1; rm /tmp/f;mkfifo /tmp/f;cat /tmp/f%7C/bin/sh -i %26

Comment: @anubhava these types of request i want to avoid

Comment: Please check below answer.

Comment: @anubhava i have updated the urls, if the url has any special characters other that @= then it should return http status code or we can redirect to home page

Comment: @anubhava yes exactly , if they are not available in that case as well it should behave normal .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are trying to filter query strings only, you could add this on top of your rules:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} !^[a-zA-Z0-9&=@?]*$
RewriteRule . /index.php [R=404,L]
```

**Note**: You only have to put allowed characters in character class.

Comment: If the url don't have a-zA-Z0-9&=/ these values then it should not fail it should fail only in case if it has any special characters other that @=

Comment: Hence there is a `!` which negates matching pattern.

Comment: `@` wasn't in your requirements. I added it.

Comment: It is failing in case url is like https://acb.com/index.html. How we can handle this

Comment: Updated my question now it is matching but not redirecting to my page which i have created.Getting Not Found error

Comment: So what does it do if  itdoesn't redirect? any error? did you try to add a leading slash `/test.html`?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/168066/discussion-between-developer-and-revo).

Comment: File is there on the server but when i am redirecting it i am getting error file not found .

Answer (score 0):

You can use this rule as your **top rule** to block all requests with characters you don't want to allow:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} [A-Z]{3,}\s/+\S*[^/\w?&=.@-]\S*\sHTTP [NC]
RewriteRule ^ - [B,F]
```